# Data imputing in questionnaires

Tags: multiple-imputation

Does anyone have experience in dealing with data imputing in questionnaires? I have a table representing people's preferences in clothes. Some of values I already have but others are missing and I'd like to make some type of imputing.

Does anyone have papers containing substantiation of using some particular imputing algorithm for such type of data?

Comment: If you don't have any additional information, you can impute the missing values by randomly sampling the non-missing values and evaluate the performance by variance-within and variance-between(the classic Little Robin method for multiple imputation). OR, if you have significant predictors, then you can use a regression model to predict the missing values.

Comment: There are hazards involved in imputing data.  Can you just use the data you have or collect more data?  How much data is missing and how much complete data do you have?

Comment: I want to clarify my problem. My dataset contains human likes or dislikes of some items. Thus my table contains 1, 0 or NA. I want to impute all NA values. Initially just a small amount of cells are filled but with time we will have much more values (instead of current NA). We want to constantly fill missing values with imputed. Maybe there might be 1 imputing algorithm for situation with just few filled cells and another for many filled values?! Did anyone have such experience of dynamical imputing procedure selection?